# Как удалить сообщение respond (Interaction Object) (pycord)

Tags: python, discord, pycord

Я хочу удалить сообщение от бота. Оно отправляется через respond. Как после этого его удалить? функция delete_after мне не подойдет, ведь я использую флаг кнопки. Все последующие respond удаляются без проблем, но самый первый, как я понимаю, так просто не удалить. Что можно сделать?

Вот мой код:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="announcement", description="Отправить уведомление для всех владельцев серверов", guild_ids=[1066303266260000829])
async def annoucement(ctx, title:discord.Option(str, required=True), description:discord.Option(str, required=True)):
    if not await bot.is_owner(ctx.author):
        embed = create_embed("Ошибка!", "Данную команду может использовать только создатель бота", 0, 255, 0, 0, ctx.guild.name)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, ephemeral=True, delete_after=5)
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title,
                          description=description,
                          colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 0, 0), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    confirmation = await ctx.respond("Подтвердите отправку оповещения:", ephemeral=True)
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed, ephemeral=True, view=MyView())
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(event.wait(), timeout=10)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.respond("Вы не подтвердили отправку оповещения.", ephemeral=True)
        await confirmation.delete()
        return
    guilds = bot.guilds
    process = await ctx.respond(f"Отправление уведомлений в процессе... Всего {len(guilds)} серверов", ephemeral=True)
    for server in guilds:
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{server.name}",
                         icon_url="убрал ссылку на всякий случай, тут просто картинка")
        owner = server.owner
        await owner.send(embed=embed)
    await process.delete()
    await ctx.respond("Отправление уведомлений завершено!", ephemeral=True)
```